# For any regular expression for a finite automata, how do you find the shortest word accepted?

Tags: regular-expressions, finite-automata

So in the question

*"For the following regular expression α over the alphabet
{a, b}, find one of the shortest words in the language L(α) defined by this expression"*

a*abab*

As far as I understand, the answer is "aba" as this is the shortest accepted word.

What if the question instead said...

*"For the following regular expressions α over the alphabet
{a, b}, find one of the shortest words in {a, b}* \ L(α)"*

a*abab*

What does the extra expression "{a, b}* \ L(α)" do to this question?

Comment: As I know the complement of regular expression is regular too. So you can write the regular expression for complement and use the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re correct that $aba$ is the shortest word in $L(\alpha)$. The set $\{a,b\}^*\setminus L(\alpha)$ is the set of all words in $\{a,b\}^*$ that are *not* in $L(\alpha)$, or in other words, all words over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ that are not in the language $L(\alpha)$. In general, if $A$ and $B$ are any sets, $A\setminus B$ is the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $B$; you may be more familiar with it in the older notation $A-B$.

If $L(\alpha)$ is the language defined by the regular expression $a^*abab^*$, the shortest word in $\{a,b\}^*\setminus L(\alpha)$ is *very* short!

Comment: What is the language L(α) ?

Comment: @sam: I took it to be the one defined earlier in the question, i.e., the language defined by the regular expression $a^*abab^*$. If you meant the two questions to be completely independent, then of course the second can’t be answered until we know what $L(\alpha)$ is.

Comment: Oh yes I see now, thank you.

Comment: @sam: You’re welcome. (I modified the answer to take this into account.)

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that, this question is essentially asking the shortest word possible which *isn't* accepted by this expression? As it is asking for the shortest word out of all variations of 'a' & 'b' excluding any words which the expression would accept. Therefore making the shortest word an empty word?

Comment: @sam: Yes, that’s exactly right.